# How to copy a file between locations in a Rackspace Cloud Files container with their PHP API

Tags: php, rackspace-cloud

Given the code

```
$this->cf_container->copy_object_to($file, $this->cf_container, $new_path . '/' . $file_subpath);
```

where $this->cf_container is an object of the CF_Container class, I get this error:

"Specified object 'A random container/one/pow/whiskey.jpg' did not exist as source to copy from or 'A random container' did not exist as target to copy to."

The container's name, obviously, is "A random container". I have tried this with a container that does not contain spaces to the same effect.

If I do a $this->cf_container->get_object($file) I get a CF_Object object with the file's properties, so it exists.

$file is equal to "one/pow/whiskey.jpg"
$new_path is equal to "one/different_folder"
$file_subpath is equal to "whiskey.jpg"

Anyone have a clue or has encountered this before?

Comment: If you're sure the files & folders exist, chances are its a permissions issue. You may have to use chmod to grant read permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try the new [Rackspace PHP SDK](http://docs.rackspace.com/sdks/guide/content/php.html) (aka php-opencloud). The php-cloudfiles will eventually be deprecated.

To copy an object in php-opencloud check out [DataObject::Copy](http://docs.rackspace.com/sdks/api/php/dataobject.inc.html#DataObject%3a%3aCopy%28%29). If you run into problems, you can file issues [here](https://github.com/rackspace/php-opencloud/issues).

Comment: Hey Everett - this looks pretty good, but I can't really afford the 5.3 PHP requirement. Is there a way to copy an object from one location to another within a container with php-cloudfiles?

Comment: Everett, I got in touch with the excellent Rackspace support and they tracked it down to a double-encoded slash. Thanks for nudging me in the right direction!