# CloudFiles cannot to copy between virtual directory

Tags: cloud, rackspace, cloudfiles

I try to copy a couple of files located on my container using the method

```
CF_container->copy_object_to('th/image_a.jpg',Object(CF_container),'th/image_a_copy.jpg')
```

But when I try to copy a file that exists I got this message

```
Specified object 'container_name/th/image_a.jpg' did not exist as source to copy from or 'container_name' did not exist as target to copy to.
```

What I doing wrong? This operation is impossible to do? This operation cannot allowed?

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using the SDK from php-cloudfiles. The copy_object_to function can be found on github [here](https://github.com/rackerlabs/php-cloudfiles/blob/master/cloudfiles.php#L1502-1573).

That library has been deprecated in favor of [php-opencloud](https://github.com/rackspace/php-opencloud). The documentation can be found [here](http://docs.rackspace.com/sdks/guide/content/php.html)

The new function to use when copying an object is DataObject::Copy and can be found [here](https://github.com/rackspace/php-opencloud/blob/ade9333d90cd9070bf6357df30017461a894fac8/lib/OpenCloud/ObjectStore/Resource/DataObject.php#L474-508).

The programming logic to make a copy of a Cloud Files object with the php-opencloud library would look something like the following:

```
// we must include this file
require_once "php-opencloud.php";

define('AUTHURL', RACKSPACE_US);

// create new Rackspace connection
$connection = new \OpenCloud\Rackspace(AUTHURL,
                array('username' => USERNAME, 'apiKey' => APIKEY));

// connect to ObjectStore
$object_store = $connection->ObjectStore();

// create a container named CONTAINER_NAME
$cont = $ostore->Container();
$cont->Create(array('name'=>CONTAINER_NAME));

// create an object in that container
$obj = $cont->DataObject();
$obj->Create(array('name' => 'test_obj', 'content_type' => 'text/plain'), __FILE__);

// copy it to another object
$target = $cont->DataObject();
$target->name = $obj->Name().'-COPY';
$obj->Copy($target);
```

If you are unable to upgrade to using the php-opencloud library, it looks like another user had a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940942/how-to-copy-a-file-between-locations-in-a-rackspace-cloud-files-container-with-t) and tracked it down to a double-encoded slash.